# Jquery display divs on loop one at a time and fade

Tags: jquery

I have these 5 divs:

```
<div id="content-1"></div>
<div id="content-2"></div>
<div id="content-3"></div>
<div id="content-4"></div>
<div id="content-5"></div>
```

and what I am trying to is the following, start off by displaying the first div, after 30 seconds, fade that div out and content-2 in and after 30 seconds, fade content-2 out and content-3 in and so on, once it has reached the end, start back at 1.

This is what I got started on, right now content-1 will start and after 5 seconds it will disappear and content-2 will appear, there has just gotta be a better way and there is no way to tell when it gets to 4 and starts at 1 again.

```
$('#content-1').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
$('#content-2').hide(0).delay(5000).show(0);
```

I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with [Jquery Timing](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content-1" class="content"></div>
<div id="content-2" class="content"></div>
<div id="content-3" class="content"></div>
<div id="content-4" class="content"></div>
<div id="content-5" class="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
var divs = $('.content').hide();
divs.each($).fadeIn(1000).not(divs.last()).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000,$);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way but it works and is easy to understand.  This code will loop through a set of elements fading them in and out one at a time.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 5000);
 var start = $('.slideshow > img').first();

 function showDiv() {
  start.fadeOut(function(){ 
   if(start.next().length==0) {
    start=$('.slideshow > img').first();
    $('.slideshow > img').first().fadeIn();  
   } else {
    start.next().fadeIn();
    start=start.next();
   }
  });
 }
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.slideshow img { display: none; }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img class="slides1" src="slide_1.jpg" alt="" style="display: block;" />
  <img class="slides2" src="slide_2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="slides3" src="slide_3.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="slides4" src="slide_4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```